# Manually invoking mouse clicks XNA

Tags: c#, input, xna, gamepad

I wish to make a simple program that is used with a gamepad and can controll mouse and keywords events from outside of the program. My goal is to be able to control the computer from the couch.

My current code in `Update()`

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    //if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
    //    Exit();

    var gamePadStates = Enum.GetValues(typeof (PlayerIndex)).OfType<PlayerIndex>().Select(GamePad.GetState);
    var mouseState = Mouse.GetState();

    var direction = Vector2.Zero;
    const int speed = 5;


    // Gamepad
    foreach (var input in gamePadStates.Where(x => x.IsConnected))
    {
        if (input.IsButtonDown(Buttons.DPadDown))
            direction.Y += 1;
        if (input.IsButtonDown(Buttons.DPadUp))
            direction.Y -= 1;
        if (input.IsButtonDown(Buttons.DPadLeft))
            direction.X -= 1;
        if (input.IsButtonDown(Buttons.DPadRight))
            direction.X += 1;

        direction.X += input.ThumbSticks.Left.X;
        direction.Y -= input.ThumbSticks.Left.Y;
    }


    var oldPos = new Vector2(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y);

    if (direction != Vector2.Zero)
    {
        var newPos = oldPos;
        direction *= speed;
        newPos += direction;
        //newPos.X = MathHelper.Clamp(newPos.X, 0, GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Width);
        //newPos.Y = MathHelper.Clamp(newPos.Y, 0, GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Height);
        Mouse.SetPosition((int)newPos.X, (int)newPos.Y);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("New mouse pos = {0}, {1}", newPos.X, newPos.Y);
    }

    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

**EDIT:**
For sending key presses I've found [this](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this in XNA is the same way as normal C#. To use the code below, make sure you are using the `System.Runtime.InteropServices;` namespace.

Disclaimer: I would consider this somewhat "dirty" code, it uses `user32.dll` to invoke the click in Windows, but it is really the only way. (Adapted from [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/321029-how-to-simulate-a-mouse-click-in-c/))

First off, you need 4 constants to easily use different types of clicks:

```
private const int MouseEvent_LeftDown = 0x02;
private const int MouseEvent_LeftUp = 0x04;
private const int MouseEvent_RightDown = 0x08;
private const int MouseEvent_RightUp = 0x10;
```

You will then need to hook into the mouse events:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void MouseEvent(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons,uint dwExtraInfo);
```

You can now write methods to create mouse clicks:

```
LeftClick(int x, int y)
{
     MouseEvent(MouseEvent_LeftDown | MouseEvent_LeftUp, x, y, 0, 0);
}

RightClick(int x, int y)
{
     MouseEvent(MouseEvent_RightDown | MouseEvent_RightUp, x, y, 0, 0);
}
```

...etc, etc. You can see how you can adapt this to also create hold/drag events to mimic more functionality.

Note: I'm not sure if this will register with the `MouseState`, but that shouldn't be needed because you are trying to use it to control the computer, and the game should never need to use the mouse state.